# Using coord_flip() with facet_wrap(scales = "free_y") in ggplot2 seems to give unexpected facet axis tick marks and tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a faceted plot with flipped co-ordinates where one and only one of the axes are allowed to vary for each facet:

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg)
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales = "free_y") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

This plot is not satisfactory to me because the wrong tick marks and tick labels are repeated for each plot. I want tick marks on every horizontal axis not on every vertical axis.

This is unexpected behaviour because the plot implies that the horizontal axis tick marks are the same for the top panels as they are for the bottom ones, but they are not. To see this run:

```
p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg)
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales = "fixed") + coord_flip()
```

So my question is: is there a way to remove the vertical axis tick marks for the right facets and add horizontal axis tick marks and labels to the top facets?

As Paul insightfully points out below, the example I gave can be addressed by swapping x and y in qplot() and avoiding coord_flip(), however this does not work for all geoms for example, if I want a horizontal faceted bar plot with free horizontal axes I could run:

```
c <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
c + facet_wrap(~cut, scales = "free_y") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

These facets have a variable horizontal axes but repeated vertical axis tick marks instead of repeated horizontal axes tick marks. I do not think Paul's trick will work here, because unlike scatter plots, bar plots are not rotationally symmetric.

I would be very interested to hear any partial or complete solutions.

Comment: I think your point is valid. You could either send an e-mail to the ggplot2 mailing list, or create a ticket at the ggplot2 github issue tracker.

Comment: Done. https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/673

Comment: Keep us posted as to the updates

Comment: You can not use free scales with a non-Cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: ggplot2 really needs to do a better job about warning you of that :/

Comment: Thank you, Hadley and thank you for ggplot. I assume that the co-ordinates I used are not Cartesian because I used coord_flip() instead of coord_cartesian(), which means they aren't default Cartesian coordinates from the point of view of ggplot2.

Comment: If you're really desperate you could try to write a horizontal version of `geom_bar` (`geom_hbar` or `geom_barh`): I ended up doing this with `geom_linerange` in a similar situation.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. In the end I used `facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales = "free") + coord_flip()` and then I deleted the extra tick marks and labels in Acrobat. This worked in my particular case because the vertical axis was a factor variable which was invariant across facets, but it would not work in general.

Comment: @orizon the coordinate system in your second example is non cartesian as one of the axes is non-continuous, but a factor.

Comment: @Paul I agree, but the problem exists in the first example as well, which clearly has Cartesian coordinates. So I think the reason for failure wasn't the factor but was `coord_flip()`, which ggplot views as a separate coordinate system, I think.

Comment: I've fixed the problem in https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1756. Welcome to review & test it. You can use devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2", ref=github_pull(1756)) to install the fixed version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the second or third time I have run into this problem myself. I have found that I can hack my own solution by defining a custom geom.

```
geom_bar_horz <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "bin", position = "stack", ...) {
  GeomBar_horz$new(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat, position = position, ...)
}

GeomBar_horz <- proto(ggplot2:::Geom, {
  objname <- "bar_horz"

  default_stat <- function(.) StatBin
  default_pos <- function(.) PositionStack
  default_aes <- function(.) aes(colour=NA, fill="grey20", size=0.5, linetype=1, weight = 1, alpha = NA)

  required_aes <- c("y")

  reparameterise <- function(., df, params) {
    df$width <- df$width %||%
      params$width %||% (resolution(df$x, FALSE) * 0.9)
    OUT <- transform(df,
              xmin = pmin(x, 0), xmax = pmax(x, 0),
              ymin = y - .45, ymax = y + .45, width = NULL
    )
    return(OUT)
  }

  draw_groups <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, ...) {
    GeomRect$draw_groups(data, scales, coordinates, ...)
  }
  guide_geom <- function(.) "polygon"
})
```

This is just copying the geom_bar code from the ggplot2 github and then switching the **x** and **y** references to make a horizontal barplot in the standard Cartesian coordinators.

Note that you **must** use `position='identity'` and possibly also `stat='identity'` for this to work. If you need to use a position other than identity then you will have to eddit the [collide function](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-collide.r) for it to work properly.

Answer (score 8):

Using `coord_flip` in conjunction with `facet_wrap` is the problem. First you define a certain axis to be free (the `x` axis) and then you swap the axis, making the `y` axis free. Right now this is not reproduced well in ggplot2.

In your first example, I would recommend not using `coord_flip`, but just swapping the variables around in your call to `qplot`, and using `free_x`:

```
p <- qplot(hwy, displ, data = mpg)
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I get your question now. I would avoid using `facet_wrap` and `coord_flip` together. Just reverse your variables in the call to `qplot`. See my updated answer.

Comment: This works well for point graphs but not for histogram. I am currently having the same issue with bar plots that I want to be horizontal and can't find a way around.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been trying to do a horizontal barplot, and run into this problem where I wanted to `scales = "free_x"`. In the end, it seemed easier to create the conventional (vertical) barplot), rotate the text so that if you tip your head to the left, it looks like the plot that you want. And then, once your plot is completed, rotate the PDF/image output(!)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(var ~ group, scale = "free", space = "free_x", switch = "both") +
  theme(axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=90), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
                     strip.text.x = element_text(angle = 180))
```

The main keys to do this are to `switch = "both"`, which moves the facet labels to the other axis, and the `element_text(angle=90)` which rotates the axis labels and text.