# unwanted axis w/ facet_wrap with scales = "free_x"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Maybe this is a duplicate not sure ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560858/using-coord-flip-with-facet-wrapscales-free-y-in-ggplot2-seems-to-give-u)).

I want to use `coord_flip`, `facet_wrap` and the argument `scales = "free"`.  If one does so this adds unwanted scales in between the facets that are unnecessary.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(gear),  y=carb, fill=vs)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    coord_flip() + 
    facet_wrap(~ carb, ncol=2)
```

Produces:

[image]

but adding the `scales = "free"` makes the axise/scales appear in the middle of facets rather than at the bottom as above.  How can I make them go away.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(gear),  y=carb, fill=vs)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    coord_flip() + 
    facet_wrap(~ carb, ncol=2, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a case of coord_flip and facet_wrap getting confused as to what is the x axis and y axis

Comment: Further to my example see the results of `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear,y=carb,fill=vs)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~carb, scales = 'free_y',ncol=2)`

Comment: It does so by design. Since the `axes` are now `free`, they no longer share a common one that could be displayed at the bottom. Makes sense, right? If it just displayed one at the bottom (i.e. they shared one), then the `free` is not required.

Comment: @Maiasaura I think Tyler's referring to the expectation that if you free the x axis and then flip the coordinates, the resulting graph should have individual axes on the vertical axis, but _not_ the horizontal.

Comment: [Related](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/95) [issues](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/673) from github. Sadly, from Hadley's comments, a happy ending doesn't look promising.

Comment: Thanks @joran, I appreciate the explanation!

Comment: I'll upvote it joran though don't like it. :(

Comment: @TylerRinker: You might be able write a `geom_bar_horizontal()` that doesn't require `coord_flip`, then you could just swap the `x` and `y` and use `free_y` instead.