# Faceting bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I have this problem: I want to build a stacked bar plot with the faceting capabilities, so I can compare the distribution of frequencies for five common categories, within two different objects, separated according to three groups. I have six objects, five categories and three groups. The problem is that each group has only two different and exclusive objects to plot, but so far I can only produce a plot in which the six objects are plotted across the three groups. This is not optimal, since for each group I have four objects with no data.

Is it possible to plot just two objects for each group with the faceting capabilities?

**EDITED**

This is my data:

```
structure(list(Face = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("LGH002", "LGH003", "LGM009", 
"SCM018", "VAH022", "VAM028"), class = "factor"), Race = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
.Label = c("1. Amerindian", "2. White", "3. Mestizo", "4. Other races", 
"5. Cannot tell"), class = "factor"), Count = c(19L, 0L, 13L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 
7L, 23L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 29L, 6L, 3L, 29L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 38L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 30L, 9L, 0L, 1L), Density = c(0.475, 0, 0.325, 0.2, 0, 
0.05, 0.175, 0.575, 0.15, 0.05, 0.025, 0.025, 0.725, 0.15, 
0.075, 0.725, 0, 0.275, 0, 0, 0, 0.95, 0.025, 0, 0.025, 0, 
0.75, 0.225, 0, 0.025), School = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Municipal", 
"Private Fee-Paying", "Private-Voucher"), class = "factor")), 
.Names =c("Face", "Race", "Count", "Density", "School"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

This is the code I'm using to build the plot:

```
P <- ggplot(data = races.df, aes(x = Face, y = Density, fill = Race)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
P + facet_grid(School ~ ., scales="free") + coord_flip()
```

As you can imagine, I only want to see the x-values "SCM018" and "LGH002" in "Municipal"; "LGM009" and "LGH003" in "Private-Voucher"; and "VAH022" and "VAM028" in "Private Fee-Paying" (only two objects per group). Is it possible? Any help?

All the best,

Mauricio.

Comment: Your data is not easy to load into R in its current format. Instead of the data sample you posted, please post the output of `dput(mydata)` (where you should of course substitute the actual name of your data frame for `mydata`).

Comment: @eipi10 Is the data better presented now? Really sorry, just learning how to use ggplot (and also Stackoverflow). Best!

Comment: Yes. Now anyone can easily load your data into R and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the problem here is that `scales="free"` doesn't work with `coord_flip()`. Without `coord_flip()`, you can do this: `P + facet_grid(. ~ School, scales="free")`. Is that what you want, but with the x and y axes flipped?

Comment: @eipi10: That's what I want, exactly, but with the x and y axes flipped. In any case, I didn't try before without `coord_flip()`, so I'm happier with this result. All in all, do you think is it still possible to flip the plot axes? Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560858/using-coord-flip-with-facet-wrapscales-free-y-in-ggplot2-seems-to-give-u), looks like a geom override can help.