# How to add an empty gap between specified axis labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add an empty gap between labels and question represented in the y-axis. Preferably without altering the dataframe.

[image: the plot]

Im trying to add an empty gap/increase the distance between the labels that are not bolded and the ones that are. While keeping the distance between the bolded/non-bolded ones the same. Is that possible? I tried to add an extra "empty" label to the data but I could not get that right. Also tried to add an "empty" line to the plot. Also adjusted the positions, but that changed the relative distance of all of the labels. Here is an example of where Im now:

```
plot_data <- data.frame(
    Evaluation = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
    Mittari = rep(c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), times = 3),
    value = runif(12),
    Kansallinen = runif(12)
)

custom_labels <- c("\"Are you happy?\"", "\"Are you sad?\"", "\"Is the student happy?\"", "\"Is the student sad?\"")
ss <- data.frame(Mittari = unique(plot_data$Mittari), custom_label = c("Yes", "Yes", "Agree", "Agree"))
plot_data <- plot_data %>%
    left_join(ss, by = "Mittari")


ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, y = value, fill = Evaluation)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), width = 0.45) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0, color = 'National average')) +
    geom_errorbar(data = plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, ymin = Kansallinen, ymax = Kansallinen, group = Evaluation, width = 0.45), position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)) +
    geom_text(aes(group = Mittari, y = 0.35, label = custom_label), size = 3.3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -2.1, colour = "grey8") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "darkorange", "lightgreen")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "steelblue", "darkorange")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 100),
                       breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1),
                       minor_breaks = NULL,
                       limits = c(0, 1)) +  # Set the limits to 0 and 1 (100%)
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), labels = custom_labels) +
    labs(y = "", x = NULL, color = NULL) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1),  # Change the order of fill legend
           color = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = ifelse(seq_along(unique(plot_data$Mittari)) <= 2, "plain", "bold"), color = "black"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use facets. Create a new variable, assigning a label to your discrete y values ( e.g. called "question_set", with values "question1", "question2"), and then add for example +facet_grid(question_set ~.) to your plot.

Using coord_flip can be problematic, especially with facets. There used to be big issues with this (see for example [How to make a a horizontal, faceted bar chart with free scales and space in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573587/how-to-make-a-a-horizontal-faceted-bar-chart-with-free-scales-and-space-in-ggpl?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [In ggplot2, coord_flip and free scales don't work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052000/in-ggplot2-coord-flip-and-free-scales-dont-work-together?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [How can I remove empty factors from ggplot2 facets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183292/how-can-i-remove-empty-factors-from-ggplot2-facets)), but those seem to have now been resolved.

However, you will need to change your "limits" argument to "breaks", otherwise your free scales will naturally not work.

Alternatives to `coord_flip` is most importantly simply flipping your x and y aesthetic, or the `ggstance` package (which is arguably more and more obsolete, but still has some important features like positions to dodge vertically)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

plot_data <- data.frame(
  Evaluation = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
  Mittari = rep(c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), times = 3),
  value = runif(12),
  Kansallinen = runif(12)
)

custom_labels <- c("\"Are you happy?\"", "\"Are you sad?\"", "\"Is the student happy?\"", "\"Is the student sad?\"")
ss <- data.frame(Mittari = unique(plot_data$Mittari), custom_label = c("Yes", "Yes", "Agree", "Agree"))

plot_data <- plot_data %>%
  left_join(ss, by = "Mittari") %>%
  ## new lines here
  mutate(question_set = ifelse(Mittari %in% paste0("M", 1:2), "question1", "question2"))


ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, y = value, fill = Evaluation)) +
  ## using geom_col instead
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), width = 0.45) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0, color = 'National average')) +
  geom_errorbar(data = plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, ymin = Kansallinen, ymax = Kansallinen, group = Evaluation, width = 0.45), position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(aes(group = Mittari, y = 0.35, label = custom_label), size = 3.3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -2.1, colour = "grey8") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "darkorange", "lightgreen")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "steelblue", "darkorange")) +
  facet_grid(question_set ~., scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() + 
  ## change "limits" to "breaks"
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), labels = custom_labels) +
  ## use NULL throughout
  labs(y = NULL, x = NULL, color = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is there a reason why the bolding of the custom_labels (e.g. the questions "Is the student..?" and so) is not working after changing limits to breaks in scale_x_discrete? I would still like to have those. And is there a way adjust the "gap" between the facets? Im using the theme_minimal so it could be larger

Comment: Dont mind the "gap" in my question, I figured it out. But bolding is still bothering me.

Comment: @Billyboy using vectors like you did to specify fonts within theme is not a good idea, and especially bad when using facets (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843759/ggplot2-coloring-axis-text-on-a-faceted-plot) . The best is to use the ggtext package here  (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862303/customize-ggplot2-axis-labels-with-different-colors)