# Plotting a single variable on the y-axis and multiple on the x-axis

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, bots

I am attempting to create a plot focused on two pieces. The first being a unique user_agent_string on the y-axis, and 5 other variables on the x-axis. This then would be faceted based on classification of the user_agent_string. I would then like to iterate through my user_agent_strings and plot each one with its respective variable values.

For reference I have provided a crude whiteboard drawing of what I would hope for.

[image: Plot Format]

Currently I am able to create this format:
[image]

With this code:

```
col<-names(gbuas_focus[,6:11])

for(i in col) {
  print(i)
  ua_p<-ggplot(gbuas_focus,aes(color=duplicate)
  )+
    geom_point(aes_string(
      x=i,
      y='uas_id'),
      size=3,
    )+
    labs(x='Variable Score',
         y='User Agent Strings',
         title="Understanding Misclassifying Variables"
    )+
    facet_wrap(~classification)
  print(ua_p)
}
```

I would assume this could be done using multiple for loops, but I am having an egregious time figuring it out. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Here is the REAL dput output:

```
    structure(list(uas_id = c("UAS1", "UAS2", "UAS3", "UAS4", "UAS5", 
"UAS6", "UAS7", "UAS8", "UAS9", "UAS10", "UAS11", "UAS12", "UAS13", 
"UAS14", "UAS15", "UAS16", "UAS17", "UAS18", "UAS19", "UAS20"
), uas_count = c(1380544L, 1133471L, 830636L, 646202L, 433693L, 
432073L, 423441L, 313840L, 303530L, 270289L, 221152L, 201028L, 
178423L, 169872L, 142562L, 130877L, 128819L, 111131L, 102078L, 
96986L), classification = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bot", 
"Human"), class = "factor"), duplicate = c("No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), phantom_etsl = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), headchr_plugins = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), headchr_chrome_obj = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), headchr_permissions = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L), chr_memory = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), mq_screen = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

EDIT 2: With the help of @SimonWoodward I was able to configure the following code to give me at least most of what I needed.

```
gbuas_focus %>%
  gather(key, value, one_of(col))%>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=key, y=value, color=duplicate), size=2) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~uas_id) +
  labs(y='Score', x='Variable', title="Understanding Misclassifying Variables")
```

[image]

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you can provide a reproducible example, e.g. by including the output of `dput(gbuas_focus)` in your question.

Comment: I have added the output. @JonSpring

Comment: dput() output is text other people can use to reproduce your run. A picture of the data is of little use.

Comment: You might not need to use loops. If you get the data in a dataframe, you can use facet_wrap or facet_grid, and coord_flip to switch x and y

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560858/using-coord-flip-with-facet-wrapscales-free-y-in-ggplot2-seems-to-give-u

Comment: @SimonWoodward Thank you for correcting my mistake. I have now uploaded the correct code.

Comment: It's not correct. There are 4 copies.

Comment: So you want a facet of facets?

Comment: I suppose a 'facet of facets' could be a solution @SimonWoodward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
gbuas_focus <- structure(list(user_agent_string = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 13L, 14L, 14L,
15L, 15L), .Label = c("Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148",
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148",
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-G960U Build/PPR1.180610.011; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Mobile Safari/537.36",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
), class = "factor"), uas_id = c("UAS1", "UAS2", "UAS3", "UAS4",
"UAS5", "UAS6", "UAS7", "UAS8", "UAS9", "UAS10", "UAS11", "UAS12",
"UAS13", "UAS14", "UAS15", "UAS16", "UAS17", "UAS18", "UAS19",
"UAS20"), uas_count = c(1380544L, 1133471L, 830636L, 646202L,
433693L, 432073L, 423441L, 313840L, 303530L, 270289L, 221152L,
201028L, 178423L, 169872L, 142562L, 130877L, 128819L, 111131L,
102078L, 96986L), classification = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("Bot", "Human"), class = "factor"), duplicate = c("No",
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes",
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), phantom_etsl = c(0L,
0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L), headchr_plugins = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), headchr_chrome_obj = c(2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L), headchr_permissions = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L), chr_memory = c(2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L,
2L, 2L, 2L), mq_screen = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-20L))

library(tidyverse)

col<-names(gbuas_focus)[6:11]

gbuas_focus %>%
    gather(key, value, one_of(col)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x=key, y=value, colour=duplicate), size=2) +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(uas_id ~ classification) +
    labs(y='Score', x='Variable', title="Understanding Misclassifying Variables")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is nearly it. Is there some way to incorporate the uas_id over each variable? This format is exactly what I am seeking.

Comment: I am hoping to make the output to look like my whiteboard sketch above.

Comment: Mainly I want to have only one uas_id have a corresponding plot @SimonWoodward

Comment: It looks better when you resize it.

Comment: Is there a way to have a plot for each uas_id follow this similar scheme?

Comment: Your new version is excellent. I would hope to separate each uas_id into their own plot. Your version has them all together. This is why I had a for loop initially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194851/discussion-between-kinkade-and-simon-woodward).